# Add Merge Field in Docusign Email Template Body

Tags: docusignapi

I have a field called "CustomerName"(text field) on contact Object in salesforce.I have created it as a merge field in docusign.Now I want to display the merge field in docusign email template subject or body.

How to display a merge field in docusign email template subject or body .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data in the Email Body and Subject then you don't need to create a merge field, you'll want to use [CEM and CES](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Custom_Button_Logic.pdf#page=4) in your button and relate the field in the text.

```
CES='{!Opportunity.Account}- Please Sign this agreement';
CEM='Hello {!Contact.Name}, Please sign this agreement electronically by clicking View Documents below.';
```

Comment: Could you provide any example for this

Comment: We need to use this CEM and CES in apex rest code,am I right?

Comment: I'd suggest having a go at the documentation I linked above; it explains exactly how DocuSign custom buttons work in SFDC.

Comment: Yes its fine, but I'm using VF page to do this.When I click a custom button on vfpage  email has to be sent to the signer.Can we achieve.

Comment: Could you please explain to me with example  how to add email body(message) and email subject line from json to docusign template                 Note : Json string has to be passed as http request.